# To make the selected part of a UILabel as Bold

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I have two UILabels, both will have the dynamic text but interrelated.
for example:

```
label1.text=@"Abc";
label2.text=@"Meaning of Abc is ......";
```

Now label2 will always have label1.text plus some extra text.

I want to make this part in label2 to be in Bold.

So far I found that it could be done by drawing the text in drawRect but that seems to be very complicated.

Is there any other way out is possible??

Thanks

Ben

Comment: You can use ***OHAttributedLabel***. Please check the example for more detail [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/blob/master/AttributedLabel%20Example/Classes/AttributedLabel_ExampleAppDelegate.m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 6 will supported attributed label for this sort of thing. Until then or if iOS 5=< compatibility is important to you, you can make the label a `UIWebView` and use HTML markup. Or do it the hard way with drawRect (which will perform better).

Edit: There are third party libraries that add attributed labels, [Nimbus](http://docs.nimbuskit.info/interface_n_i_attributed_label.html) is one of them that works well.

Comment: not tried Nimbus yet, my problem is resolved by using OHAttributedLabel, will also try Nimbus later on if required,anyways thankyou so much for your reply:)